# Is there a reason why the Eclipse build cannot find a Maven lib

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Is there a reason why eclipse can't find this lib when it is added in Maven dependency with success.

Is there an error here ?

[image]

[image]

This is the Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependency mentioned is not the correct dependency since it is not the artifact of the RESTEasy JAX RS Implementation. Therefore it neither contains `org.jboss.resteasy.ClientRequest` nor `org.jboss.resteasy.ClientResponse`.

In order to have access to the required classes, the dependency ought to be used is the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: how about this propriety? ${resteasy.version}

Comment: @zebiridjallil, you can use the same version you were using for the `resteasy-jackson-provider`: 2.3.1.GA.